# Combine two ID's in SQL to get a Primary Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Maybe someone can help me with my problem in tsql:

In my sql database every country got a different ID, f.e.:

**Country - ID**

- Germany - 1
- Austria - 2
- Suisse - 3
- Italy - 4

Every product in my database got his own ID either, but in a different way:

**Product - ID**

- Bike - (100,1,2)
- Car - (200,1,4)
- Train - (2000,1,2)

Now, I would like to create a PK / FK for every combination (with exactly 14 numbers).
It should look like the following way:

10 *(Country_ID)* 00 *(2nd No. of Product_ID)* 0 *(3rd No. of Product_ID)* 000 *(1st No. of Product_ID)*

**Example:**

- Germany Bike = 10100102000100
- Suisse Bike = 10300102000100
- Germany Car = 10100104000200
- Germany Train = 10100102002000
- Italy Train = 10400102002000

My problem is that the first No. of the product-ID sometimes got three digits and sometimes got four digits, but the PK/FK should always have exactly 14 digits.

I already tried a lot of different ways to do it, but have not reached the desired code yet.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Thanks you so much!

Comment: I would strongly advise against this approach. You're giving meaning to the primary key of the table. Further, you're making it all into a single column that's going to be very difficult to update & change. Even more, you won't be able to guarantee referential integrity on this. What happens if the ID for Italy changes (yeah, unlikely, but possible). Better would be to build a compound key out of the actual columns, not a calculated column like this.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this? This feels very much like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: What do you want to do when first no of ProductID got four digits? Do you want to remove one '0' from the last or ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove one "0" of the three "0" 's which are in front of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not the nice approach, you can achieve this by;

```sql
select 
concat(
    '10',
    cast(ID as varchar(3)),
    '00', 
    SUBSTRING(ProductID,CHARINDEX(',',ProductID)+1,1), 
    '0', 
    SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(ProductID,CHARINDEX(',',ProductID)+1,len(ProductID)),charindex(',',SUBSTRING(ProductID,CHARINDEX(',',ProductID)+1,len(ProductID)))+1,1), 
    case when len(substring(ProductID,1,charindex(',',ProductID)-1))=4 then '00' else '000' end,
    substring(ProductID,1,charindex(',',ProductID)-1)
)
from so1
```

Comment: In future, you should actually explain your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had to adjust a few little things, but now I got it.
I know that this is not the best way to do it, but I need it in my tables this way.

Comment: @DavidG yes you are right. That was a bit superficial.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that's a good idea.

But is your problem the part where 4-digit code should have one less zero in the preceding position? Then use `lpad()`.